# z-index at drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

For my board i have a div where i can drop imgs wich can be dragged around in the board.

i use

```
 drop: function (event, ui) 
{
    ui.draggable.clone(false)
    .removeClass('original ')
    .addClass('draggable').appendTo($(this))
    .draggable({stack: ".draggable", containment: '#board' })
    .resizable
    ({containment:'#board',aspectRatio: true})
    .css({position: 'absolute'})
;}
```

at drop

and i use

```
 .draggable({stack: ".draggable", containment: '#board' })
```

to set the last dragged item at the top.

But when i add a new one and the last image is set to the size of div board, the newly dropped item won't be visible cause it has a lowe z-index (stack).

Is there a way to get the highest z-index and give it 1 more to the newly added one?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could build yourself a function and loop through them fetching the highest z-index value.

```
assignHighestZ = function(elements,newElement) {
   var _z = 0;

   elements.each(function() {
      if(parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) > _z) {
         _z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
      }
   });

   z++;
   newElement.css('z-index',z);
}
```